# Is it a good idea to install ubuntu server on mac mini server machine?

Tags: ubuntu, mac

I bought this to do LAMP development, but I'm tired of all the restrictions and simplicity that comes with Mac Lion Server,

I wanna install ubuntu server on that machine and say good bye to all the GUI niceness that comes with it.

I have two questions for this

1- Is this a good idea? is it possible? 
2- How am I gonna install ubuntu while Mac Mini Server does not come with a CDROM
3- Am I going to have a nightmare with drivers and compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently running a Mini as a cheap KVM virtual host server - because you can squeeze two into a single RU, they're quiet, and use relatively little power.

The secret is to install using the 11.10 'alternate' disk, located [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/11.10/release/ubuntu-11.10-alternate-amd64+mac.iso), which will get around the biggest issue which is botoing under Apple's UEFI. My next recommendation is to keep a small OS X partition on the disk, and ensure that you run a system update piror to the Ubuntu install, to ensure that your firmware is as up to date as possible. You may need that OS X partition in future to install other firmware updates from Apple.

There's a whole stack of step-by-step instructions (that I read and ignored) on the Ubuntu community documentation wiki [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation) on what you want to do.

1. Yes - if you're not afraid to get your hands dirty;
2. You can either beg/borrow/steal an external CD/DVD drive (which is my preferred option), or install from a USB stick [instructions found here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick) (I did ask if you weren't afraid to get your hands dirty!);
3. With Ubuntu 11.10, the only issues with drivers I've had are DRM (direct rendering), which won't affect you as you're not running a GUI.

Finally, to the comment that it's 'not supported' - Linux was never supported on a whole stack of architectures that it was ported to originally - if we all had the 'not supported' philosophy, we'd not have the freedom of Linux on so many architectures now.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing something supported (and this sounds more like a SuperUser question); I'd try installing it in a Virtualbox VM and that way you won't need to worry about compatibility or drivers or anything else, plus you sandbox the dev environment.